# Сборка приложений Qt из-под x64 платформы для x32 платформы

Tags: linux, qt, gcc, g++

Необходимо написать приложение с использованием фрэймворка Qt на x64 операционной системе под x32 системы.

Установленная ОС: Arch Linux x86_64.

Компилятор gcc/g++ поддерживает multilib.

Qt ставил через менеджер пакетов (qt5-base, qtcreator). Версия Qt5.7. Собираю через qmake.

Comment: `CFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-melf_i386` если коротко. Если вообще классно хочется, то используйте `CROSS_COMPILE=` и соответствующий префикс всем командам в *Makefile*.

Comment: @Oandriy пишет: /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.0: error adding symbols: File in wrong format  Такое ощущение, что мои либы только под x64 заточены... Хотя утилита 'file' выдаёт следующее: /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64